# HTTP2 with defined proxy function that supports http requests in golang

Tags: go, proxy, http2

I have a specific use case, where I have to use HTTP2 protocol with a proxy configured. This proxy function uses the request to determine, which proxy URL to use.

Since `http2.transport{}` struct does not have a proxy field, I was using:

```
httpTransport := &http.Transport{
    Proxy:             *ProxyFunction, // var ProxyFunction *func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error)
    ForceAttemptHTTP2: true,
}
http2.ConfigureTransport(httpTransport)
```

But, this does not allow me to send "http://" requests as HTTP2. Only "https://" were sent as HTTP2, "http://" requests were using HTTP1.1

This leads me to

```
    httpTransport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy:             *config.ProxyFunction,
        ForceAttemptHTTP2: true,
    }
    h2, _ := http2.ConfigureTransports(httpTransport)
    h2.AllowHTTP = true
```

But using this config, on request, I receive
`error getting: Get http://google.com: http2: no cached connection was available`, similar to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26479

Since there is no official support, what would be the right approach to achieve this?
Can I use a dialer to achieve this?

---

Note:

- proxy URL is obtained from `ProxyFunction *func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error)` and changes based on the request
- `https` is not a requirement and need not be supported.

`go version go1.13.7`

Comment: What if you try to use some static proxy URL using `http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)` ? You face the same issue?

Comment: Yeah, I tried this as well to no avail. Go does not have official support for proxies with HTTP2. Had to abandon this idea